# Ignore Ada Function Return Values

Tags: language-features, ada

Is there a way to ignore return values in `Ada` functions?

I have a function which imports from an Intrinsic.

```
subtype int32 is Interfaces.Interger_32;

function Intrinsic_Sync_Add_And_Fetch
    (P : access int32; I : int32) return int32;

pragma Import(
            Intrinsic, 
            Intrinsic_Sync_Add_And_Fetch, 
            "__sync_add_and_fetch_4");
```

If I want to use this in a procedure, I need to accept the return value or I will get a compiler error:

```
cannot use function Intrinsic_Sync_Add_And_Fetch in procedure call.
```

But, if I create a variable that simply takes the return value of the function and is never used then I get compiler warnings. Obviously, I'd rather avoid those.

I can't very well assign the value *back* to the value I'm adding to; this would undermine the point of the `add` operation being atomic.

There is the option of taking the value and doing *something* with it, like:

```
val := Intrinsic_Sync_Add_And_Fetch(...);
if val := 0 then null; end if;
```

It forces the code to compile without errors or warnings, but it seems stupid to me. How can I "get around" this language feature and safely ignore the return value?

**Edit: What is __sync_add_and_fetch_4?**

This is a built-in atomic operation available on Intel CPUs. As such, part of my `Autoconf`/`Automake` process would be deciding if the operation is available, and use a fallback implementation, which involves a critical section, if it's not.

You can read about this and similar operations in [GCC's section on atomic builtins](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.0/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html#Atomic-Builtins).

The `__sync_add_and_fetch_4` does pretty much exactly what it says. In `C`, it would look something like this:

```
int32_t __sync_add_and_fetch_4(int32_t *ptr, int32_t value) {
    *ptr += value;
    return *ptr;
}
```

So it's an atomic addition operation, which returns the result of the addition. Basically, it's an atomic `+=` operator.  The `_4` means that it takes a 4-byte integer.

***Edit***: I understand that I could probably just switch off that particular compiler warning, but that always feels dirty to me. If there's a solution available that allows me to continue using `-Wall -Werror` then I'd love to see it.

Comment: As i dont know about the "__sync_add_and_fetch_4" operation could you enlighten me/us about its usage ? Is P the value you want to use & the return value the one you want to ignore ?

Comment: OK, updated the question with a small explanation of the atomic add op. And yes, I want to ignore the return value of that function. What it's returning is the result of the operation, which is also stored in `P`. I guess the only reason it returns the same value is to make it chainable. I don't need that.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I would reccomend you go with a wrapper function. This is because in Ada the signature of a function _includes_ the return type, so to get the pragma import to work correctly (bind to the right thing), you will need a return value. Your wrapper function specification should look like what Simon Wright suggested, and with an internal of what oenone suggested.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
declare
   dummy : constant return_type := my_function;
   pragma Unreferenced (dummy);
begin null; end;
```

or write a wrapper procedure.

Comment: `pragma Unreferenced` is a GNAT special, which might be a disadvantage.

Comment: Seems to be the best option for now. At the moment I'm only supporting GNAT but that might change.

Comment: @Simon: The warning is GNAT special, too. Any other compiler might act differently. So Unreferenced is justified.

Answer (score 5):

You said you're only targeting the GNAT compiler. The [GNAT User's Guide](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_ugn_unw/Warning-Message-Control.html) says:

> Note that a special exemption applies to variables which contain any of the substrings DISCARD, DUMMY, IGNORE, JUNK, UNUSED, in any casing. Such variables are considered likely to be intentionally used in a situation where otherwise a warning would be given, so warnings of this kind are always suppressed for such variables.

So the simplest solution to your problem is :

```
unused := Intrinsic_Sync_Add_And_Fetch(...);
```

Though you might want to wrap that in a procedure if you are going to use it more than a couple of times :

```
procedure Intrinsic_Sync_Add_And_Fetch(P : access int32; I : int32) is
   unused : int32;
begin
   unused := Intrinsic_Sync_Add_And_Fetch(P : access int32; I : int32);
end Intrinsic_Sync_Add_And_Fetch;
```

Comment: Wow, I am just learning Ada, but this seems like a very odd design decision for GNAT to make, Magic variable names? What if I wanted to use the variable `idontcare`? :P

Answer (score 4):

If you never want to reference the return value, why not declare the subprogram as a procedure? The value is going to be returned in a register, so throwing it away won’t cause a lot of grief. (I stand to be corrected on this one!)

```
subtype int32 is Interfaces.Integer_32;

procedure Intrinsic_Sync_Add_And_Fetch
    (P : access int32; I : int32);

pragma Import(
            Intrinsic, 
            Intrinsic_Sync_Add_And_Fetch, 
            "__sync_add_and_fetch_4");
```

Comment: OK, cool. Can anyone confirm that this is safe? I wondered about what would happen if I imported a "wrong" function signature.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know of any way to ignore the return value of a function in Ada: the language has been especially designed to force you to store those return values.

personally, i would store the return value and ignore any warning regarding the use of the variable. anyway, the said warning is quite strange since the variable is indeed used to store the return value.

Comment: Yes, but the value is not referenced. It's possibly a cross-over warning from C & C++. Basically, it's redundant memory because it's not being used. Maybe if I compile with -On, it will optimise it away?